# How do I connect open VPN Ubuntu server with a windows client?

Tags: windows, configuration, vpn, openvpn

I have configured an OpenVPN server on my Ubuntu machine with the help of this link https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/openvpn.html.
I can connect my Open VPN server with Ubuntu client. Now I want to connect with Windows machine. How do I connect my Ubuntu OpenVPN server with a Windows machine? Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a `.ovpn` file (with your appropriate `ca.crt`, `client1.crt`, `client1.key`) and use this file in your windows machine. For this purpose you need a windows client.

You can use `openvpn` client for windows as described [here](https://openvpn.net/index.php/access-server/docs/admin-guides-sp-859543150/howto-connect-client-configuration/395-how-to-install-the-openvpn-client-on-windows.html).

The downloads are in [here](https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/downloads.html).

Comment: But i have to describe the different parts and then reference to sources.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake and voted on the wrong answer.